# React OnClick inside stateless function does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I am using react-google-maps to make a map with markers that show InfoWindows, where you are able to press a button to print something to the console. I use the following code, but the onClick does not execute the function:

```
function Map() {

  const [selectedKalas, setSelectedKalas] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });

  function sendMergeRequest() {
    console.log("Sender merge request");
  };

  /* Fetching some data... */

   useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(database_url_coordinates);
      setData(result);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <GoogleMap>
      {
        data.data.map(kalasobjekt => {
          if (kalasobjekt.username !== "admin" && kalasobjekt.kalas !== null) {
            return (
                  <Marker
                    key={kalasobjekt.kalas.id}
                    position={{
                      lat: parseFloat(kalasobjekt.kalas.lat),
                      lng: parseFloat(kalasobjekt.kalas.lng)
                    }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setSelectedKalas(kalasobjekt);
                    }}
                  />
                )}
            );
          }
        }))
      }
      {selectedKalas && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={{
            lat: parseFloat(selectedKalas.kalas.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(selectedKalas.kalas.lng)
          }}
          onCloseClick={() => {
            setSelectedKalas(null);
          }}
        >
              <div>
                <h2>{selectedKalas.username}</h2>
                <p>Eier: {selectedKalas.kalas.fullName}</p>
                <p>Kapasitiet: {selectedKalas.kalas.capacity}</p>
                <div className="submitData">
                  <button onClick={sendMergeRequest}>
                    Merge hos {selectedKalas.username}!
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}
```

I have been searching around and trying to understand why this doesn't work but cant seem to find any good anwsers. I hope

Comment: can you try logging the value of selectedKalas after click? something like below : useEffect(()=> {console.log(selectedKalas)},[selectedKalas])

Comment: Tried onClick={() => SendMergeRequest()} ? Also, not best practice to give functions/methods capital letters to start with (convention is for classes, enums to start with capitals).

Comment: just noticed that there is no data attribute in the initial value of state data. it should be { hits: [], data:[] }

Comment: Tried onClick={() => sendMergeRequest()} (I changed the name) it didnt work

Comment: Also tried logging the value of selectedKalas. I wrote onClick={() => console.log(selectedKalas)}. But nothing showed up in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function Hello() {
    const handleClick = function handle(){
        alert('Btn is clicked');
    }

  return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ handleClick }>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u3hLy4j/)

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping this function **SendMergeRequest** method outside of function **Map** should work.

**Example:**

```
function Map() {
// map code
}

function SendMergeRequest() {
  console.log("Sender merge request");
};
```

Comment: I tried it and put: ```<button onClick={() => sendMergeRequest()}>```but it didnt work